# ConcurrentModificationException - Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, exception, runtimeexception

Have crash in Crashlytics which I cannot reproduce and don't know where it occurs. Posting all received logs below.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.main.MainActivity}: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException 
Caused by java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next (ArrayList.java:573)
android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.restoreInstanceState (NavigationMenuPresenter.java:587)
android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.onRestoreInstanceState (NavigationMenuPresenter.java:191)
```

As you can see from logs NavigationMenuPresenter and NavigationMenuAdapter are classes in android.support.design.internal. From the names of it looks like it has something to do with Navigation Drawer menu and some ArrayList (correct me if I'm wrong). Does some error occur when trying to restore state of menu?

Here is code for navigation menu creation

```
private void setupDrawer(Toolbar toolbar) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        initAvailabilityChange(navigationView);
        initMenuHeaderViews(navigationView);
    }

    private void initAvailabilityChange(NavigationView navigationView) {
        switchItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.availability);
        CompoundButton switchView = (CompoundButton) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(switchItem);
        switchNew = (Switch) switchView.findViewById(R.id.switchLocation);
        switchView.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            isOnShift = isChecked;
            presenter.onAvailabilityChange(isOnShift, this);
            if (isChecked) {
                switchItem.setTitle(R.string.availability_on_shift);
            } else {
                switchItem.setTitle(R.string.availability_off_shift);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initMenuHeaderViews(NavigationView navigationView) {
        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        tvName = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvRank = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tvRank);
    }
```

Would be really grateful for any help.

Comment: You need to look in your code, for where you iterate over an ArrayList and modify items on the loop. And share that code, and we'll help :)

Comment: Please add the code around `NavigationMenuPresenter.java:587` to your post

Comment: can you share your code in `onRestoreInstanceState()`?

Comment: @torkleyy NavigationMenuPresenter is not my class, it is part of android.support.design.internal

Comment: @hsl onRestoreInstanceState() is method in NavigationMenuPresenter in android.support.design.internal

Comment: @KhrystynaPochynok, check my comment above..

Comment: It seems the exception is not related with the code or did you forget to post a few lines of the backtrace?

Comment: @torkleyy no, I didn't forget to post some lines of backtrace. It is all I got. It is not pointing at any line of my classes otherwise I wouldn't ask this question. But I've already managed to locate the problem - it is because of custom view in navigation drawer containing switcher. Just need to figure out how to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be an issue with ViewGroup implementation. Try to post a new Runnable.

```
switchView.post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    if (isChecked) {
                switchItem.setTitle(R.string.availability_on_shift);
            } else {
                switchItem.setTitle(R.string.availability_off_shift);
            }
  }
});
```